# Compiler error: Property not recognized

Tags: c#, class, generics

I have a list which contains the 'Reference' class as a generic type. So I should be able to fill my list with children of the 'Reference' class, but the compiler reports an error:

> `'naturalCalc.Enginee.Reference'` does not contain a definition for `'Opener'` and no extension method `'Opener'` accepting a first argument of type `'naturalCalc.Enginee.Reference'` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) `ToPostfix.cs:27,34`

The switch code in the 'ToPostfix' class ensures that the item has 'Opener' property in the second case.

```
// The 'MyBrackets' class which contains the 'Opener' property.
public class MyBrackets : naturalCalc.Enginee.Reference
{
    private bool opener;
    public MyBrackets( bool opener )
    {
        this.opener = opener;
    }

    public bool Opener { get { return this.Opener; } }
}
```

---

```
// The 'ToPostfix' class in which the error is taken place.
class ToPostfix
{
    List<Reference> infix = new List<Reference>();
    List<Reference> postfix = new List<Reference>();

    public ToPostfix(List<Reference> infixForm)
    {
        this.infix = infixForm;

        foreach (Reference item in this.infix)
        {
            switch ( item.ToString() )
            {
                case "naturalCalc.Enginee.MyFloat":
                    this.postfix.Add(item);
                    break;

                case "naturalCalc.Enginee.MyBrackets":
                    if (item.Opener)
                    {
                        this.postfix.Add(item);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to move the method into the interface if possible.

If this is not possible you can test the type dynamically and cast as follows:

```
Opener opener = item as Opener;
if (opener != null)
{
        if (opener.Opener)
        {
            this.postfix.Add(item);
        }
}
```

Also your getter doesn't work correctly. You should also learn to use auto-implemented properties:

```
public class MyBrackets : naturalCalc.Enginee.Reference
{
    public MyBrackets(bool opener)
    {
        this.Opener = opener;
    }

    public bool Opener { get; private set; } // Auto-implemented property.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **not a complete answer**, but I believe that there's an error on your MyBrackets class.
`opener` and `Opener` are not the same property.

I believe it should be:

```
public class MyBrackets : naturalCalc.Enginee.Reference
{
    public MyBrackets(bool opener)
    {
        this.Opener = opener;
    }

    public bool Opener 
    {
        private set { this.Opener = value; }
        get { return this.Opener; } 
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: The OP just needs a lowercase `opener` in the `get`.  `public bool Opener { get { return this.opener; } }`

Comment: @Kevin yes, that would be enough =)

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `List` of `Reference`, but defining the `Opener` property in the `MyBracketClass`. If you want your property to be accessed from a `Reference` instance, move it there.